# Create a D3 axis without tick labels

Tags: d3.js, label

How can I create a D3 [`axis`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) that does not have any labels at its tick markers?

[Here's an example that shows what I'm after](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048740), from Mike Bostock no less. There are several Axis objects rotated around the centre, and only the first one has tick labels.

In this case, he's achieved the result using CSS to hide all but the first axis's labels:

```
.axis + .axis g text {
  display: none;
}
```

However this still results in the creation of SVG `text` elements in the DOM. Is there a way to avoid their generation altogether?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I'm just going to leave this here since people are likely to end up on this question. Here are the different ways you can *easily* manipulate a D3 axis.

- Without any ticks or tick labels:

  ```
  d3.svg.axis().tickValues([]);
  ```

  No `line` or `text` elements are created this way.
- Without ticks and with tick labels:

  ```
  d3.svg.axis().tickSize(0);
  ```

  The `line` elements are still created this way.

  You can increase the distance between the tick labels and the axis with `.tickPadding(10)`, for example.
- With ticks and without tick labels:

  ```
  d3.svg.axis().tickFormat("");
  ```

  The `text` elements are still created this way.

Comment: With the newer (typescript) API it will be something like  `d3.axisBottom().tickFormat((domainn,number)=>{return ""});`

Comment: That's wrong. The only thing that needs to change (due to D3v4, not typescript) is `d3.svg.axis.orient("bottom")` to `d3.axisBottom()`. `tickFormat` accepts a string just like it always has.

Comment: @Ashitaka - I believe that @Himanshu is correct. Typescript throws an error for me when `tickFormat` is passed a string instead of a function

Comment: Are you aware of a full working example? When I add this code to my d3 script I get TypeError: svg.axis is not a function.

Comment: Same here, I got an error when trying to use tickFormat("") - tickFormat((d)=>"") did work in typescript.

Answer (score 11):

You can't avoid the generation of the `text` elements without modifying the source. You can however remove those elements after they have been generated:

```
var axisElements = svg.append("g").call(axis);
axisElements.selectAll("text").remove();
```

Overall, this is probably the most flexible way to approach this as you can also remove labels selectively. You can get the data used to generated them from the scale you're using (by calling `scale.ticks()`), which would allow you to easily do things like remove all the odd labels.

Answer (score 3):

> Create a D3 axis without tick labels

A tick mark without a label can be created by using a function that returns an empty string. This works in both the Javascript and Typescript versions of D3.

`d3.svg.axis().tickFormat(() => "");`

Further explained on github *@types/d3-axis* 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24716#issuecomment-381427458

Comment: That's because the type of `tickFormat` is wrong (and should be fixed). `d3.svg.axis().tickFormat("" as any);` will work

Comment: @Ashitaka - but that doesn't work in javascript environments, where as `() => ""` works in both.

Comment: @Ashitaka - Also, if you believe "`tickFormat` is wrong (and should be fixed)" why not open an issue on the d3-axis GitHub page (https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues) for @Mbostock to review?

Comment: I don't believe that it is wrong. I _know_ that it is wrong. The issue is not with d3-axis though. d3-axis (and all other d3 libraries) are written in JS, not TS. The issue is located in the dependency that you are using to provide d3 types.

Comment: @Ashitaka - So if you know this is wrong, why not report the issue? I believe the common package that people use is `npm i @types/d3-axis`, and that you can report the issue on the GitHub page (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues)

Comment: I don't use d3 with TypeScript. And it's not my fault that the project DefinitelyTyped is badly run. See PR 4805 which was accepted and PR 24716 which was rejected. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/4805 https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24716

Comment: So in summary, @types/d3-axis recommend solution (PR 24716) is to use a function that returns an empty string `() => ""`

Comment: Which is wrong, because `""` works. DefinitelyTyped typed the function incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but if you are using D3 version 7 probably this approach will help you.

There are 4 axes: top, left, bottom and right. We will define the left and bottom as main axes, and top and right as tick-less axes.

There are two way to render tick-less axes either declaring empty array for the `tickValues` function like this:

```js
xAxisTop = d3.axisTop().scale(xScale).tickSize(0).tickValues([])
```

Or declaring an empty label for the tick using `tickFormat` function like this:

```js
const yAxisRight = d3.axisRight().scale(yScale).tickSize(0).tickFormat('')
```

However, both require that we define the `tickSize` function to `0` to avoid the default ticks at the start and the end of the axis.

This is working snippet:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('plot')
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50,
}
const width = 600, height = 180
const data = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]

const svg = d3.create('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height])
  .attr('style', 'max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;')

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale)
const xAxisTop = d3.axisTop().scale(xScale).tickSize(0).tickValues([])

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale)
const yAxisRight = d3.axisRight().scale(yScale).tickSize(0).tickFormat('')

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(yAxis)

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${width - margin.right}, 0)`)
  .call(yAxisRight)

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(xAxis)

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${margin.top})`)
  .call(xAxisTop)

element.appendChild(svg.node())
```

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='plot' class='center'></div>
```