# horizontal lines along the y axis d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/pnyn7vzj/1/   in this plunkr how the horizontal lines along the y axis are added

I just tried adding this css code

```
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
  }
```

I want to develop bar without the x axis , I have attached an image please check with that.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code, where you define your `xAxis`. Instead of:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));
```

You should try:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickValues([]);
```

This will remove your x-axis labels and ticks. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26863774/5173530) post for more information.

Comment: how can i add horizontal  lines along the y axis , along the y axis points ..i followed the plunkr not understanding which piece of code does that

Comment: what kind of lines? the existing ones are defined where `var yAxis` is configured - where you set `.tickSize(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted clarify that Andrei Roba gave the correct answer to the original question: the piece of code in the jsfiddle that draws the horizontal lines accross the graph is

.tickSize(-width, 0, 0)

The ticks have their size set to the whole width of the graph, which effectively draws a whole line.