# d3:Adding Axis like a Box

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have d3 graph with xaxis and Y axis.I want to add axis to the top and right to make it look like a box.
Something like This.[image]

Comment: Just add 2 `line` elements with the correct `x` and `y` coords for the top and right edge. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go through this article for adding multiple axes. You should create new axis generators and give the `orient` as 'right' and `top` and call them finally.

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/using-multiple-axes-for-d3js-graph.html

**EDIT:**

I have made a simple line chart with your requirements. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/j0kaLf59/

Also as mentioned in the comments, you could just add two line elements. Have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a6o2hkfq/

Reference:

- [Create a D3 axis without tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787925/create-a-d3-axis-without-tick-labels#26863774)
- http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/create-svg-elements-in-d3js

Comment: What data should be scale then ? I mean in the Scale method scale()

Comment: I guess it should be the same data by which the left and bottom axis were created.

Comment: The problem is all the x-axis labels are repeated,which I dont want.